# Are the nodes in stack for iterative postorder traversal are always ancestors and no other node for some node?

Tags: tree, traversal, iteration

If I need to print all nodes on path to root for some node with some given property.
Can I use iterative postorder traversal to find the node and then print entire stack?

EDIT : Is there any other way to keep track of ancestors?It isn't a bst.

Answer (score 0):

One way to keep track of ancestors in a graph is to have every node store a pointer to its parent.  That way, from any node you can walk back up to the root by just iteratively following the parent pointer.  The runtime of walking such a path is O(d), where d is the depth of the node.  If you know for a fact that you're going to be walking up from nodes to the root often, this approach is strongly worth considering.

As for your original question, yes, you can use an iterative postorder traversal to find the path from any node back up to the root.  Any node on the stack will either be the node itself or some ancestor, and they'll be in the right order.  However, this is substantially less efficient than the approach of just storing parent pointers.  Finding a node can take O(n) time in a tree with n nodes, which scales poorly with the size of the tree relative to the O(d) solution outlined above.

**EDIT**:  I misunderstood what you meant by iterative postorder.  This can also easily be done with a *recursive* postorder traversal where you pass a stack by reference down through the call chain.  Here's an example in C++:

```
void RecSearchWithHistory(Node* curr, vector<Node*>& history) {
    // Base case: if the node is NULL, we're done.
    if (curr == NULL) return;

    // Mark that we've been to the current node.
    history.push_back(curr);

    // If we found what we are looking for, we now have the path
    // to the root available!
    if (/* some predicate */)
        /* ... use history ... */

    // Visit both children (assuming this is a binary tree; the
    // generalization fir multi-way trees is easy.
    RecSearchWithHistory(curr->left, history);
    RecSearchWithHistory(curr->right, history);

    // Finally, pop the stack since we are done using this node.
    history.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: With parent pointers solution is trivial.Since I don't have the node ,I have to find it given some property ,so it has to take O(n) anyway.Isn't there any any way which avoids iterative postorder traversal and parent pointers?

Comment: Not really.  If you have no idea where the node is, then you have to search the whole tree (unless you have some auxiliary structure you can use to find it faster).  Once you've found it, if you have no parent pointers, then you can't find your way back up.  You could consider using another search technique, such as doing a breadth-first search, but this has much higher memory usage than the depth-first search (iterative postorder) that you're doing.  Is there a particular reason that you don't want to do this?

Comment: As you said iterative postorder can do the job but it is sort of tricky to implement in interview .A lot of interview questions require printing all ancestors.

Comment: @drubs- My apologies, I misinterpreted what you were asking.  Check out the revised code I've posted for tracking history during a recursive walk.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible, here are my codes:

```
Node* getRightSibling(Node* parent,Node* child){
  if(parent->right == child)
    return NULL;
  else if(parent->left == child)
    return parent->right;
  return NULL;
}

void iterativePostOrder(Node* root) {
  stack<Node*> nodeStack;
  Node* current = root;

  while (true) {
    if(current != null){
      nodeStack.push(current);
      if(current->left != NULL)        //push left  sub-tree
        current = current->left;
      else if(current->right != NULL)  //push right sub-tree
        current = current->right;  
      continue;
    }

    if(nodeStack.empty()) return;

    current = nodeStack.pop();
    visitNode(current);

    Node* parent = nodeStack.top();
    Node* rightSibling = getRightSibling(parent,current);
    if(rightSibling == null) {
      //two case:
      //  1. parent has no right child
      //  2. current is the parent's right child, we complete access
      //     right sub-tree.
      //in either case we need access parent, and because parent is at
      //the top of Stack, so:

      current = NULL;

    }else{
       // we need start to access right-subtree.
       current = rightSibling;
    }
}
```

I only push nodes in the search path into stack, so in the visitNode, if you find that node is what you are searching, then the elements in the stack are the parents of that Node.